# DroneKit - setting RTL altitude

Tags: dronekit-python

I want my copter to return to launch on specific altitude, for now I am running everything on ArduPilot SITL. First I have tried to use simple_goto()

```
vehicle.commands.download()
vehicle.commands.wait_ready()
finish_location = deepcopy(vehicle.home_location)
finish_location.alt = flight_altitude
vehicle.simple_goto(finish_location)
```

simple_goto() works fine for other location, but when I use vehicle.home_location, it results with copter descending to altitude -7.5m. What is more copter is only descending, it does not fly to finish_location.

So I have tried to use RTL mode

```
self.vehicle.mode = VehicleMode("RTL")
```

It works good, but I cannot find way to set RTL altitude to my desired `flight_altitude` parameter, it runs with default 15m.

Answer (score 0):

Code below works fine.

```
vehicle.commands.download()
vehicle.commands.wait_ready()
target_location = LocationGlobalRelative(0, 0, 0)
target_location.lat = vehicle.home_location.lat
target_location.lon = vehicle.home_location.lon
target_location.alt = target_altitude
```

Still I do not understand why

```
vehicle.commands.download()
vehicle.commands.wait_ready()
finish_location = deepcopy(vehicle.home_location)
finish_location.alt = flight_altitude
vehicle.simple_goto(finish_location)
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Check my answer. You need to set `vehicle.parameters['RTL_ALT'] = 0` before sending it to home location.

Answer (score 0):

The way to set the RTL altitude is through the parameter.
If you want it to return at the same altitude set the parameter to 0.

```
vehicle.parameters['RTL_ALT'] = 0
vehicle.mode = VehicleMode("RTL")
```

Take a look at the docs.
http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/parameters.html#rtl-alt-rtl-altitude